# appengine-try-java - 500 server error

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am creating my first project on Google Cloud.  As per the instructions, I installed the Google Cloud SDK, Java 7 JDK (jdk1.7.0_80), Apache Maven and the appengine-try-java.zip.

Everything installed as per the instructions with the only exception being the appengine-try-java.zip.  When I executed the instruction: appcfg.cmd -A my-first-project-969 update D:\App\appengine-try-java I had an error that WEB-INF was not found.  I found the location and copied it to the directory of appengine-try-java.

That did work and I was able to create the project.  Everything looked like it was working.  When I went to select the URL http://my-first-project-969.appspot.com/ I get this error message:

Error: Server Error
The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.

Please try again in 30 seconds.

I wait 30 seconds and the same error appears.  Everytime I select the URL the error appears.

I have ensured I am running Java 7 JDK and the paths are all correct.  Everything seems to be working as per the instructions.  Any thoughts on what I may be doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Your appengine instance is getting an error (or is misconfigured). Go to the appengine console and look for a stacktrace or something that will give you a clue as to what the problem is. Your console should be at: https://console.developers.google.com/project/my-first-project-969/logs

Comment: Thanks, I took a look and found an exception to a DemoServlet.java not found.  However, it is in the code.  I suspect it may be in the wrong place.  I'll take a look at the code.

Comment: The code is fine.  The DemoServlet.java is there.  Everything should be working as I followed the exactly information.